# Fetching secrets by just name when using AWS SecretManager in cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to fetch pre existing secrets from the `aws-secretsmanager` module on CDK, and from the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-secretsmanager-readme.html), the suggestion is

> If you need to use a pre-existing secret, the recommended way is to
>   manually provision the secret in AWS SecretsManager and use the
>   Secret.fromSecretArn or Secret.fromSecretAttributes method to make it
>   available in your CDK Application

However, both the methods demand the use of the `arn` to fetch the secrets. I am not sure if it is a good idea to hardcode arns and check them into the git repo. Instead is there a way to just fetch the secrets by just using the name, since we already have the account details available in the profile for cdk.

Comment: There is an open [github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7444) for this feature request which was opened 25 days ago from today.

Answer (score 0):

At least until this current version (1.38.0), it’s not possible. An alternative is to save the secret arn in the SSM parameter store and use the ssm key in the code.

Comment: There is a caveat though. It doesn't work when you want to use the secrets to create resources that don't support dynamic referencing. The complete list of resources where you can use SSM parameter store for secrets is listed here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

Comment: @KeshavPotluri that's true when reading the parameter using `ssm.StringParameter.valueForStringParameter`, but you could bake them at synthesis time by using `ssm.StringParameter.valueFromLookup`

Comment: yes you are correct. It works well with regular strings, but not secrets. I've basically tries every way possible using SSM and Secrets Manager, and Secrets Manager works the best with secret strings in almost all the cases. SSM does work for specific resources, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Putting full ARNs in CFN should not be a concern. Since you are creating these secrets ahead of time, their name, account, and region will be know. If you wish, however, you could still use the CFN psuedo parameters for partition, region, and account (AWS::Partition, AWS::Region, AWS::AccountId or the CDK equivelent).